# Commands in asp.net always run a dot net build

Tags: asp.net, .net, command, configure

Hello every time I type any dotnet command it will configure dotnet again.
I don't want to be like this, I don't want that every time I type command dotnet is configuring again. Help me turn this off.
[configure again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpRT9.png) 
[image]

Comment: It helps a lot if you mention the error message in plain text. Not everyone is willing to or capable of looking through your screenshot and finding that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "Failed to create prime the NuGet cache. new failed with: -2147352571" hints at a known problem when you install the 2.0 CLI next to the 1.0 one and then return to run anythin in 1.0 afterwards.

Latest information on this topic is from June this year when the 2.0.0 tools were still in preview phase. The info back then was to wait until 2.0.0 is released and then there might be another update to the 1.0 series to fix problems if both are installed together.

In the meantime, you can work around this by either uninstalling the 2.0 series dotnet cli or by making sure this environment variable is set before running the 1.0 cli again:
`DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=1`

This is the original problem report with the same error message you didn't mention: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6381
Here's the discussion for the temporary fix: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6550#issuecomment-301261209

And here you find the latest information about no updates for the 1.0 series until 2.0 is final (2.0 is final in the meantime, but apparently 1.0 hasn't received any updates since): https://github.com/dotnet/cli/pull/6633#issuecomment-311882413

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was helpful :)